# Possibility of headless GPU rendering using Singularity?

Tags: x11, nvidia, opengl, singularity

I have a C++ program that uses VTK to render images internally (no window appears while executing the code).

I have access to an HPC cluster and I've managed to run the code using a OSMesa version of VTK on the CPU-only nodes with SingularityCE, naturally being CPU it's about 10 times slower that using GPU locally. The HPC also has nodes with NVIDIA A100s GPUs in them.

I know that Singularity has the `--nv` flag to make visible the NVIDIA driver to the container and I've managed to call `nvidia-smi` inside, that works.

But so far, the resources I've found (such as [this](https://dugas.ch/lord_of_the_files/run_your_unity_ml_executable_in_the_cloud.html)) makes use of elevated privileges setup the virtual graphics enviroment, which I can't use, for example, calling `nvidia-xconfig --query-gpu-info` inside the container gives a permission error.

Is there any way to render OpenGL (through VTK) in a headless server without root privileges with Singularity?